# How to add objects to a list with a thread and use the list at the same time without getting ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, arrays, thread-safety

The title tells it all, I have a Timer t1 which periodically adds objects to a List. 
Then I have an other Timer t2 iterating on the list at constant intervals to display its content.

I totaly understand why i'm getting these exceptions but I can't come up with the right answer to avoid it. Iv'e tried running my operations in synchronized(list){} and such things but nothing makes it. My algorithm apears to be working just fine despite these exceptions but i would like to make it clean nontheless.

Any idea?

Edit:
I'm using java.util.Timer;

Comment: if you are using synchronized, all code that touches the list must synchronize on the same object. Make sure that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All access to the List much be wrapped by a synchronized block like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public final class Answer {
    private static final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5 * 1000;
    private static final int TWO_SECONDS = 2 * 1000;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // this list contains the values that the producer will add to and the consumer will pull from
        final List<Long> theList = new ArrayList<>();

        // consumes all values found in theList
        new Timer("consumer").scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<Long> copy;
                synchronized (theList) {
                    // we make a copy and clear theArray as quickly as possible in 
                    // order to not block the producer for too long
                    copy = new ArrayList<>(theList);
                    theList.clear();
                }

                System.out.println("copy = " + copy);
            }
        }, 1, FIVE_SECONDS);

        // adds the current time in ms to theList every 2 seconds
        new Timer("producer").scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (theList) {
                    theList.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            }
        }, 1, TWO_SECONDS);
    }
}
```

That being said using a BlockingQueue will do this for you.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine to avoid conflicts. My problem was that i was trying to access the list from just a class and not a thread so the mutex wasn't working. Though, now my problem is I need a high refresh rate on the display of my information so waiting for the access to be available is slowing down the refresh rate substentialy. What iv'e been doing instead of adding stuff and displaying it using only one list is simply having a list to which i add my objects and then make a copy of it to display its content. So with 2 instancies i'm avoiding conflicts. Not optimal but it does the job.

Comment: Ok so i managed to make it work using semaphores, though i had to make a kind of wack system with it but at least it doesn't pump ressources like using 2 array instances did and the refresh rate is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.baeldung.com/java-mutex Maybe take a look at mutex-structures, these might come in handy

Comment: Managed to make it work using semaphores/mutex, thank you.